# Generics Set with Enums

Tags: java, generics, enums, interface, enumset

Problem space has been stripped down.

So I have the following interface that I cannot change.

```
public interface ItemInterface {
  Set<Enum<?>> getItems();
}
```

I have created the Items enum class

```
public enum Item{
  ITEM1, ITEM2, ITEM3 
}
```

So when I implement the method It does not compile.

```
public class ItemImpl implements ItemInterface {

    @Override
    public Set<Enum<?>> getItems() {
        Set<Item> vals = new HashSet<>();
        vals.add(Item.ITEM1);
        return vals;  
    }
}
```

The return type does not match and I get compile errors?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply declare the `vals` as `Set<Enum<?>>`:

```
public class ItemImpl implements ItemInterface {

    @Override
    public Set<Enum<?>> getItems() {
        Set<Enum<?>> vals = new HashSet<>();
        vals.add(Item.ITEM1);
        return vals;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, `return new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton(Item.ITEM1));`.

Comment: @AndyTurner `Collections.singleton()` could also be replaced with `Set.of()` or `EnumSet.of()`

Answer (score 0):

How about this, I have changed the interface, coz simply its makes a bit readable. If your interface is part of any other package, @Lino answer can be used

```
public interface ItemInterface {

    Set<? extends Enum> getItems();
}



public enum Item implements ItemInterface{
    ITEM1, ITEM2, ITEM3;

    @Override
    public Set<? extends Enum> getItems() {
        Set<Item> as = new HashSet<>();
        as.add(ITEM3);
        return as;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP said: *So I have the following interface that I cannot change.* thus this is not a real option

Comment: Also, returning a wildcarded type is bad, as is returning a partially raw type.